# Check state of checkboxes created at runtime

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I'm using VS2010 on Windows 7 (64-bit)

I've created checkboxes at the runtime and now I'm stuck in a position that I'm not able to check the state of them. When a button is clicked, I wanted to know which check boxes are checked.. Please guide me.

Code:

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Data(10) As String
    Dim name(10) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim offset = 10

    i = 0
    Data = Form1.cmail
    name = Form1.cname

    For Each cur In Data
        If cur Is vbNullString Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Dim checkBox = New CheckBox()
        Dim labelBox = New Label()
        Me.Controls.Add(checkBox)
        Me.Controls.Add(labelBox)
        checkBox.Location = New Point(10, offset)
        checkBox.Text = Data(i)
        checkBox.Checked = False
        checkBox.Size = New Size(150, 20)
        labelBox.Location = New Point(160, offset)
        labelBox.Text = name(i)
        labelBox.Size = New Size(1000, 20)
        offset = offset + 30
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: why check the state of a checkbox in button click versus the checkchanged event of the checkbox?

Comment: I need to do some operations on the result and pass those values to the parent form and that's why I needed it to be done in button click.. But still, thinking of it, it's also a way that works fine for my requirements... Thanks.. And Btw, which is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these textboxes into a list hence you can search which text boxes are checked in a button click.

```
Dim cheklist As New List(Of CheckBox)' creating list of checkboxes
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Data(10) As String
    Dim name(10) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim offset = 10
    i = 0
    Data = Form1.cmail
    name = Form1.cname
    For Each cur In Data
        If cur Is vbNullString Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Dim checkBox = New CheckBox()
        Dim labelBox = New Label()
        Me.Controls.Add(checkBox)
        Me.Controls.Add(labelBox)
        checkBox.Location = New Point(10, offset)
        checkBox.Text = Data(i)
        checkBox.Checked = False
        checkBox.Size = New Size(150, 20)
        cheklist.Add(checkBox) ' add created check box to the ckeckboxList
        labelBox.Location = New Point(160, offset)
        labelBox.Text = name(i)
        labelBox.Size = New Size(1000, 20)
        offset = offset + 30
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
'*****Display the textboxes which are checked****
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each chk As CheckBox In cheklist
            If chk.Checked = True Then
                MsgBox(chk.Text & "is checked")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks bro... It was so urgent at dat time, so I changed my design to use CheckBoxList.. But with some drawbacks.. Now redone the code as u said and got the result just the way I wanted.. thanks again!